# How can I use a different __consumer_offsets topic to store the offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have to create a consumer in java and I have to use a different __consumer_offsets topic.
How can I do that? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. You can change `Number of partitions` of that topic and `Replication Factor` configuring broker configs.

[offsets.topic.num.partitions](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_offsets.topic.num.partitions)

[offsets.topic.replication.factor](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_offsets.topic.replication.factor)

Comment: So I can't create a consumer that use a different __consumer_offsets topic with another name ( for example __consumer_offsets_2 ) ?

Comment: Yes, You can't do it.